# How to bypass or simulate human behavior on Google using Tor and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, tor

Im using firefox tor and selenium to automate searches , but i encounter the bot recognition. How do i get pass that?

I have already tried with some extensions.

Comment: Which site are you getting detected on? Why are you using Tor instead of a chrome selenium driver with undetected_chromedriver import.

Comment: Because the requirements say to use geckodriver and firefox

Comment: Requirements of what? You can use a chrome selenium instead.

Comment: The project asks firefox so i have to use Geckodriver!